# Detect URL open

Tags: java, android

I have an android app where in some places it may have the URLs (e.g. from push notifications, in some views where text is pulled from BE, etc.). My question is: is there any fast and good way to detect that app opens up a URL and redirect it to the web browser? I want to check the opened URL and in some cases stop app from opening web browser and do my custom action instead. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not directly. If you are using Intent Action view and passing like this

```
ContextCompat.startActivity(
            context,
            Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(appLink)),
            null
        )
```

You could use a broadcast manager sent it there and from on `onReceive` method you can call the code to launch web browser from broadcast.

You could perhaps use a WebView and intercept all request calls using this code

```
 mWebView?.setWebViewClient(object : WebViewClient() {

        override fun shouldInterceptRequest(
            view: WebView?,
            request: WebResourceRequest?
        ): WebResourceResponse? {
            LogUtils.d(request?.url)
            return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request)
        }
    })
```